# Why is insertion loss independent of load resistance?

Tags: impedance, attenuator

I am studying about attenuators and read from my lab sheet that if the source impedance equals the characteristic impedance of the attenuator, the insertion loss given by \$N = \frac{v_{1}}{v_{2}}\$ where v1 is the voltage across the load without the attenuator and v2 is the voltage across the load with the attenuator attached, will be the same regardless of the load resistance used. If the source impedance is zero, the output has to be terminated in its characteristic impedance, this is clear as we already assumed this in the derivation of the resistors value for the attenuation we desired.

How is the insertion loss kept the same when we use different load resistance if the source impedance is equal to the characteristic impedance of the attenuator?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your source is making some invalid assumptions. 'I have read that ... ' leaves us little to go on. Cite your source. Define what you understand by 'insertion loss'. Obviously if the load resistance =0, the insertion loss will be infinite (by my definition).

Comment: @Neil_UK Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the load is connected directly to the source through the transmission line it will see the characteristic impedance of the transmission line if the source impedance matches the transmission line characteristic impedance.

When the attenuator is inserted, if it has the same impedance as the transmission line, then the load sees the same impedance as previously.

So the value of the load is included in both cases. The attenuation is applied as a product, so it will reduce the attenuation independently from the load value only if the source impedance equals the transmission line impedance and the attenuator does as well.

---

Update: Here is a proof

Before the attenuator is inserted:
$$
v_{1}=v_{2}=\frac{R_{L}}{R_{g}+R_{L}}v_{g}
$$

After insertion, the attenuator presents a Thevenin source to \$R_L\$. Now \$v_{1}\ne v_{2}\$:
$$
v_{2}=\frac{R_{L}}{R_{Th}+R_{L}}v_{Th}
$$

Notice that \$v_1\$ is still the voltage before insertion. It will be different after insertion,
unless \$R_L=R_0=R_g\$. But this is not relevant to the question.

So the attenuation ratio is
$$
N=\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{R_{Th}+R_{L}}{R_{g}+R_{L}}\frac{v_{g}}{v_{Th}}
$$

Using the design equations and constraints, (\$R_g=R_0\$, the characteristic resistance of the attenuator), used in the OP:
$$
N=\frac{R_{0}+R_{L}}{R_{0}+R_{L}}\frac{v_{g}}{v_{Th}}=\frac{v_{g}}{v_{Th}}
$$

which is clearly independent from the load resistance since neither the source nor the Thevenin voltages are dependant on the load.

I leave to the reader the calculation that \$R_{Th}=R_0\$.

---

Of course if the load is changed after insertion the overall attenuation is different.

If the attenuator is to match the load resistance to the source resistance then Andyaka's answer is the one you want.

Comment: In the case when we are using a shorter wire lengths at low operating frequencies, characteristic impedance becomes less significant. With and without the attenuator attached, the load sees the same source impedance (since the attenuator is designed according to the source impedance). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> *how is the insertion loss kept the same when we use different load
> resistance if the source impedance is equal to the characteristic
> impedance of the attenuator.*

It can't. If the load resistance (\$R_L\$) doesn't match the prescribed value used in the calculations for the attenuator, then impedance matching to the output isn't achieved and neither will the attenuation (insertion loss) remain the same.

[image]

If you were to make the output (load impedance) unequal to the input impedance then the relationship between R1, R2 and R3 change dramatically: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Taper%20pad%20attenuator.html).

Comment: The question is not about impedance matching. What is given in the OP's lab sheet is correct. Read my update.:)

Comment: @RussellH I'm sorry but I strongly and wholeheartedly disagree.